# Exportar Tipo Date para openOffice/libreOffice Delphi

Tags: delphi

Como posso exportar um tipo Date para o openoffice/libreoffice
quando preciso exportar um tipo String faço da seguinte forma.

```
 SheetOpenOffice.GetCellByPosition(vCont,vlinha).SetString(Q_Assoc.Fields[i].AsString);
```

Como posso fazer quando o tipo que vem na query for um tipo Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
if ((DateToStr(Q_Assoc.Fields[i].Value) <> Null) and (DateToStr(Q_Assoc.Fields[i].Value) <> '')) then
    SheetOpenOffice.GetCellByPosition(vCont,vlinha).SetString(Q_Assoc.Fields[i].Value);
```

Comment: Deu esse erro:  InterfaceOleWrapper_Impl::Invoke : [automation bridge]UnoConversionUtilities<T>::variantToAny Cannot convert the value of vartype :"8" to the expected UNO type of type class: 11

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira, editei a resposta no lugar do SetValue coloque SetString

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira, deu certo?